# Use custom docker binary in CoreOS

Tags: docker, vagrant, coreos

I'm using vagrant to spin up CoreOS VMs. I'd like them to use a custom binary of docker. When I tried to move this binary to `/usr/local/bin/docker`, it informed me that `/usr` is read-only.

Vagrant does seem to let you [specify](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html) a version of docker to install, but I'm working with an unreleased version, and I'm not even sure the version parameter works for CoreOS.

Do I have any options here?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr` on CoreOS is read only (as indicated) but you can drop a custom binary anywhere on disk and utilize it in your unit.

CoreOS ships in alpha, beta and stable versions, each with different bug fixes. Docker 1.5.0 is the stable channel and Docker 1.6.2 is the other channels.

Is there a specific version of Docker you're looking for or a reason that you want to use a custom binary?